# PIWIK GeoIP (PECL) giving unknown location

Tags: matomo

I have installed piwik successfuly on my system. But geoIP location is not working. I have followed guide at piwik [FAQ](http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_164/) to configure GeoIP Geo location by PECL  extention. But is is always showing

> According to this provider, your current location is:
>
> Unknown

I have also placed GeoIPCity.dat in /.../piwik/misc/ but same error. I have also tried GeoIP (Php) but nothing changed. What is the problem. I am using centos on my server.