# Piwik GeoIP PECL giving uknown location

Tags: centos, pecl, geoip, matomo

I have installed piwik successfuly on my system. But geoIP location is not working. I have followed guide at piwik [FAQ](http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_164/) to configure GeoIP Geo location by PECL  extention. But it is always showing

> According to this provider, your current location is:
>
> Unknown

All my visitors also have an unknown location, so I'm guessing it can't locate IP addresses correctly. How can I fix this?

I am using centOS on my server.

I know this question is the same as [PIWIK GeoIP (PECL) giving unknown location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087377/piwik-geoip-pecl-giving-unknown-location) but no one has answered in 5 months so I'm hoping someone can answer here.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of GeoIP database? If it is outdated, you might get UNKNOWN in the results.

Comment: I am also facing this problem. The problem is piwik is not receiving public IP instead it is taking private IP 10.X . If anyone got the solution please help me out.